# Radial gradient for large block of type

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using Illustrator and doing a typography course. In order to create a bit more visual weight, I'm trying to mimic the idea of sound resonance through color. In this image

[image: type with blend tool]

I simply use the blend tool to duplicate the type and after creating outlines and expanding the shape I try using the radial gradient as I need the center to be dark and the last blocks of type to be grey.

[image: gradients for every letter]

What happens instead is that every letter gets its own gradient.

Can you guys think of a smart way to go around this. I've found a solution to my issue by manually lowering the opacity, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: See the duplicate. There's probably no reason you need to expand or create outlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group everything and then convert the group to a Compound Path. To do so, select the grouped shapes and go to `Object > Compound Path > Make`.

Then apply the gradient to it. It should work fine. I don't know how *Compound Path* does the trick, but I guess it treats it like a single shape in this case. It is often used for applying gradients like this.

[image]

You can distort the shape of Circle if you need to.

[image]